# Conditions to use Gradient Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

May I ask what are the exact  conditions to use the gradient theorem (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GradientTheorem.html)?

The website does not clearly say.

Is existence of partial derivatives enough? Or do we need something stronger like continuity of partial derivatives, etc.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma(a) = P$ and $\gamma(b) = Q$.
$$\int_{\gamma} \nabla f \cdot d\textbf{s} = \int_{a}^b \nabla f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \ dt = \int_{a}^b \frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(t)) \ dt = f(\gamma(b)) - f(\gamma(a)) = f(Q) - f(P)$$

The only thing you need for this is differentiability of $f, \gamma$.